# Ruby, Retrieve Child Object By Key

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join, inner-join

I am trying to retrieve a child object based on the key in its parent's table.  For instance, I have the Customer class which contains a "store_id" key to the Stores tables.  If a customer has a "store_id" key, I would like to bring back that Store object and not the parent Customer object.

EDIT:  Here is a sql statement showing what I am trying to do.

So the SQL statement would look something like this.

"SELECT storeS.* FROM customers INNER JOIN stores ON customers.store_id = storeS.id WHERE customers.id = '9'"

I know the sql is probably wrong, but thats a very concise way to show it.

Comment: What do you mean by "bring back"? Could you show us some sample code of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Mischa So the SQL statement would look something like this.

Comment: If that's what you want, you should follow PinnyM's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you are using rails with the out-of-the-box configuration (using ActiveRecord).

By convention, the "store_id" key in the "customers" table should match an "id" field in the "stores" table.  You should also have the following class models setup:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers # this is not required for what you want to do here, but recommended
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
end
```

Assuming this is true, you can either do this if you have the store key:

```
# assuming we have store key == 9
Store.find(key)
```

Or you could do this if you already have the customer:

```
# assuming we have customer.store_id == 9
customer.store
```

Or if you only have the customer key:

```
# assuming we have a customer key == 9
customer = Customer.find(9)
store = customer.store
```

Comment: Note that for `customer.store` to work, you'd need `belongs_to :store` defined on your `Customer` model.

Comment: @PinnyM  I have edited the original post to include a sql statement to show what I am doing. For clarification, I generally only assume that I have a customer.id.

Comment: If you are using rails with the defaults (ActiveRecord as the ORM) there is no need to write any SQL at all.  I have edited my answer to show how this should be written.

Comment: @PinnyM Thanks PinnyM ! I was hoping I would have to "touch" the Customer object, but I am new to rails, so I am currently learning to unlearn the old ways of doing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use ActiveRecord a lot, but I think it's this:

```
Store.find(customer.store_id)
```